Controlling Title Bar Color in PySide 6.7 Based on Windows Theme
I've recently noticed a change in behavior regarding the title bar appearance in PySide6. In version 6.6, the title bar of the main window always appeared white, regardless of whether the Windows theme was set to light or dark mode. However, in PySide6.7, the title bar now follows the Windows theme, displaying a light title bar in light mode and a dark title bar in dark mode.
Here's a minimal example demonstrating this behavior:
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Minimal Example")
        self.resize(300, 200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

My question is: Is there a way to programmatically control this behavior? For example, can I force the title bar to be dark when using the Windows Light theme and vice versa?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this control. Thank you!

AFAIR Qt now always follows the system mode, and right now there is no way to enforce a specific scheme. What seems strange is that you see that on the window title, which should not be affected by any of the above, since it's normally drawn by the OS. Are you sure that you just didn't notice that before, and, in the meantime, you changed some settings in your OS and/or installed some system update?

I can still test the provided example with both v6.6 and v6.7 (you can test too). While version 6.7 follows system theme in title bar, version 6.6 is always light mode.

No, I can't test, as I don't use Windows :-) The color scheme feature has changed in 6.5, and in 6.6 they introduced the QPalette::Accent color role which, AFAIK, can also affect title bars through an undocumented API. It's possible that this was changed in order to more accurately follow the expected behavior, so I'm afraid that there's no (easy) way to change that.
